# Limit the number of rows in a ListView / GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, rows

I have a ListView with a GridView used as the View, similar to the example here:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersView}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />                 
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How do I go about limiting the maximum number of rows displayed?

I've seen other examples refer to GridView.ItemsPanel (see below), but this simply does not work for me ("ItemsPanel not found in GridView").

Is my only solution to maintain the underlying CollectionView?

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="5"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my only solution to maintain the underlying `CollectionView`?

Yes. The control itself has no way of limiting the number of items.

You should control this yourself by not adding too many items to the source collection (`UsersView` in this case).

There is no way to limit the maximum number of items in XAML.

Answer (score -1):

You could just filter your `UsersView` and use the `Take` method to get the number of items you want to show.

```
UsersView.Take(5);
```

Unless you need the whole `UsersView` in other places.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking this may be the solution. I'd prefer to do it in the Xaml if possible though.